# Does Using 'git push -f' On A Remote Repo Refresh The Entire Folder?

Tags: linux, git, bash, process, crash

I have a GIT repo for an application. The application starts a long running process that I want to keep running in the background.

When I make a change to any of the application config files, commit those changes, and then git-push those changes, everything works fine. The long running process picks up the config changes I've pushed.

Sometimes though, I make a mistake in the commit history and purge those commits with a rebase. I then use git push -f to force the purged changes through. Doing so kills the long running process.

Why would that be?

As I understand it, when I git-push commits, it will only change the lines of code that I have edited.

Am I right in thinking that using git push -f instead changes more than just the lines in the commits I've purged? I suspect the git push -f command is also refreshing (though not changing) other application files in the repo, if not all of them, and that's why the process dies on a rollback attempt...

Does anyone have a definitive answer?

Comment: Why are you marking the question down without a comment? Is there something wrong with the question, or with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what your long running application is doing?  Does it have any knowledge of Git?  How does it crash?  Did you drop something that your application was using?  For instance, let's say some config value `foo` needs to be set, and after you drop your commits it's no longer there.  I assume this long running application is running somewhere other than your local machine?  FWIW, I didn't down vote your question.

Comment: Well... When I use 'git revert', the long running process does not terminate. So GIT undoubtedly treats git push -f differently to a standard git push. The local process is a long running service that's written to (hopefully) be fault tolerant. Now I'm no *nix expert, but I'm pretty sure if the executable file itself is refreshed/replaced while the process is running, then the process will die... What I would like to know is if git push -f is refreshing files that I have not ordered it not to refresh. And what happens if I decide to use -f every time, even without a rebase?

Comment: The behavior of the `--force`-flag is well described in the [manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) and states that remote references will be overwritten without any checks! You use it normally if you'd like to "overwrite" changes from other contributors. It wouldn't recommend using it permanently. Your question is so far not specific enough to give you a helpful answer, try to add more details about your problem (with edits). - besides, i didn't vote either.

Comment: `git push` doesn't affect any working tree files... it only pushes objects to the remote repository, and that's true whether or not `-f` is passed.  Now, if your long-running process is running near the repo, and you have a post-receive hook setup that's updating a working tree, then that's a different story... but that doesn't appear to be what you're describing.  What `git push` will modify are the references in the `.git` folder.  Once the other end has indicated that the refs are updated, Git will update the local versions of those refs.  But there are no working tree changes.

Comment: Ah. I do have a hook, but the same thing happens whether I use a hook or not. git-push -f will kill the process, but all 'forward' commits, including git-revert, do not. That's why I'm putting out the batsignal. Perhaps the push -f works differently when you try to change the history of the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Though I still have my suspicions, I think the issue may have just been caused by a careless commit that overwrites the file that the process is based on.

If I discover anything new (as likely as that might be), then I will update the answer.
Thanks for the help.

**Update**:

I'm pretty sure that it's not GIT now. It was because the long running process prints out messages to the terminal. When I was testing the GIT hook, I always had an SSH terminal open, so the program ran fine. But when I closed the terminal and made an upstream push from my remote machine, the application had no terminal to print messages to...

Doh.

Accounting for this appears to work.